# JQuery .val(value)

Tags: jquery

Could anyone help me understand how this code segment works?  I'm assuming it produces something like `<option value="val">text</option>,` but I just don't see how it does that.

```
$('<option></option>').val(val).html(text)
```

The above snippet is part the following code I used to add two options to a `<select>` statement.

```
var myOptions = {val1:'text1', val2:'text2'};
$.each(myOptions, function(val, text)
{
   $('#mySelect').append($('<option></option>').val(val).html(text));
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To the right when you were asking your question there was this handy **How to Format** box. Worth a read, as is [the page linked](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) from the **[?]** just above the question area. It's **very important** to properly format code in order to make your question clear. @alexn has done it for you this time, but for the next time, it's best to do it yourself at the outset.

Answer (score 3):

What it does is create an `<option>` element

```
$('<option></option>')
```

set its "value" attribute to the value of the parameter `val`

```
.val(val)
```

and set its "text" (what is "inside" the `<option>` element) to the value of the parameter `text`

```
.html(text)
```

Then, it appends the resulting element to the list of `<option>`s inside the `<select>` element with id equal to `mySelect`.

In effect, this populates the `<select>` element dynamically based on the contents of the `myOptions` object.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it interprets as

```
<option value="val">text</option>
```

Detailed:

- `$('<option></option>')`: Creates a new option element
- `.val(val)`: Gives it the value `val`
- `.html(text)`: Inserts a Text for the option

  `var myOptions = {val1:'text1', val2:'text2'};`: It defines an array which contains the `value` and `text` which is used to populate the select box

`$.each(myOptions, function(val, text) {}`: This part interate over all the myOptions available and receives the value as `val` and text as `text`.

The `$('#mySelect').append` part adds the above markup <sub>`(<option value="val">text</option>)`</sub> into the select box `$('#mySelect')` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

The code you references sets the value property of the options tag and then sets the text value.  So that it would look something like this

```
<option value="your-val">your-text</option>
```

And then you add it to the select.